# On ActiveRecord, why is foreign_key defined on the model being referenced instead of the model using it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

This might be a super newbie question. I've been a happy rails user for quite some time but have been so confused about this:

Why do we need to specify foreign_key attribute on the model that is being referenced, instead of on a model that is actually referencing it? For example why do we do this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts, :foreign_key => author_id

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
```

instead of

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => author_id
```

Maybe i'm missing something but I just thought it would make more sense if foreign_key is defined as an argument to belongs_to since `Post` table is where author_id will be defined in the database. Could someone explain? Thank you

[UPDATE]
Maybe the question was confusing. Let me clarify: I already know WHEN I need to use the foreign_key attribute, I was asking about the ActiveRecord convention of having that attribute on `User` model instead of `Post` in this particular example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to do with how rails generates the query for a `has_many` relationship. Including the `foreign_key` attribute tells rails to use that column when finding the related posts

```
SELECT posts.* FROM posts WHERE posts.author_id = self.id
```

It would fall back to the following convention if that flag was missing

```
SELECT posts.* FROM posts WHERE posts.user_id = self.id
```

You can always check the generated sql for an active_record query by calling the `.to_sql` method

```
user.posts.to_sql
```

Comment: To clarify, I already know WHEN I need to use the foreign_key attribute, I was asking about the ActiveRecord convention of having that attribute on User model instead of Post in this particular example.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify custom fk only if the key in your join table(in migration file) has other name.

Comment: To clarify, I already know WHEN I need to use the foreign_key attribute, I was asking about the ActiveRecord convention of having that attribute on User model instead of Post in this particular example.